# Can one fit an ellipse into a set of points solving a simple linear system?

Tags: numerical-methods, conic-sections

My goal is to find the equation of an ellipsis to fit the following points:

(0.120727960995591, 1.40351716270739)

(0.556408255451578, 1.22358316257310)

(0.986940854500628, 0.782393903020727)

(1.12685887538981, -0.00110809554252468)

(0.949400714131023, -0.421663826229138)

(0.618511570455713, -0.738619832947234)

Given the general formula for the curve is $$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$

in this [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tuXiwY_y_U7PmFjwizQliSr_e718Pds6M-BNsnh4YIc/edit#gid=0) I created the matrix with the coefficients $x^2$, $xy$, $y^2$ and so on, as to find its inverse and, after that, the solution to the problem. Given that matrix B is a null matrix, the only solution that I get is the trivial one.

[image]

So my question is: is it really possible to find the equation of the ellipsis in such a way? Or is it **necessary** to use a numerical method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is that the matrix $A$ becomes full rank because of the rounding errors.

Comment: Suppose  the equation of a line is $\,Ax+By+C=0.\,$ You have the coordinates of two points. How would you find the equation of the unique line that contains the two points?

Comment: @Damien can you elaborate that further?

Comment: You mean "ellipse".  An ellipsis is $3$ dots: $\dots$

Comment: @Moo yes agreed, setting constant A = 1 for example. But still, doing that gives me only the trivial solution.

Comment: @Moo let me look into that further

Comment: @Moo agree, you may be right, let me investigate further. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: A possibility is to fix $A=1$. Then you get a [overdetermined system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system)  that you solve by using the pseudo-inverse (i.e. LS solution).

Comment: @Moo your solution is perfect!

Comment: @Moo by eliminating the last point and moving x^2 to the right side, I got the following (please check the link for the spreadsheet). Even though it is not the trivial solution, it does not match yours. Am I doing something wrong? 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tuXiwY_y_U7PmFjwizQliSr_e718Pds6M-BNsnh4YIc/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Moo I changed the sharing options on Google Sheets, I believe it works now

Comment: @Moo I just realized that the equation is the same, by multiplying by a constant (found by doing 1/0.0285194). Thanks a lot for the help Moo